# Add user´s Bio in woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-data, email-notifications

In my WooCommerce web site, I am trying to add the user Biography.

Any Idea on how can I add the user´s Bio in Woocommerce emails notifications?

Comment: No, it´s not a custom field. It´s the classic user bio. I found something talking about the function get_user_meta(´description´), but I can´t arrange it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this custom hooked function in **`woocommerce_email_customer_details`** action hook:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'add_user_bio', 9, 4);
function add_user_bio( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $user_bio = get_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'description', true );
    $title = __("Biographical Info","woocommerce");

    if( empty($user_bio) ) return; // We exit if the user bio doesn't exist

    echo '<table id="user-bio" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 40px; padding: 0;" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left; border: 0; padding: 0;" valign="top" width="100%">
                    <h2 style="color: #557da1; display: block; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 130%; margin: 0 0 18px; text-align: left;">'.$title.'</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left; border: 0; padding: 0"  valign="top" width="100%">
                    <span style="border:solid 2px #e4e4e4; padding:12px; display:block;">'.$user_bio.'</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This is tested and works. You will get something like:

[image]